# Android numberpicker does not expand

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-number-picker

The android numberpicker does not expand after inserting a digit with the soft keyboard.

I'll demonstrate with an example:

1. Insert 1000 inside the numberpicker:

   [image: numberpicker small]
2. Add one "0" to the numberpicker with the soft keyboard by tapping on the numberpicker:
   [image]

   **PROBLEM HERE: numberpicker does not expand so the first digit isnt visible    anymore. The numberpicker should show 10000 instead of 0000**
3. After closing the keyboard, the view refreshes and the numberpicker expands --> this is what I already expect to happen in step 2
   [image]

Could anyone explain me why the numberpicker doesn't expand after inserting a digit ? (see step 2)

The XML layout of the numberpicker:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/article_name"
        style="@style/ApsMobile.TextView.Medium"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ll_npicker_container" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_article_amount_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/article_name"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ll_npicker_container">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/article_amount"
            style="@style/ApsMobile.TextView.Small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/article_unit_description"
            style="@style/ApsMobile.TextView.Small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/article_amount"
            android:lines="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- container is needed to center the percentage vertically-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_npicker_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

        <be.axi.aps.model.ArticleNumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/rnpicker_pickingline_amount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_symbol"
            style="@style/ApsMobile.TextView.Medium"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right" />
    </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please share the xml